# How to fix duplicates in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that is supposed to return a count and average of per person however I'm getting duplicate values for people. I checked the formatting of the names but not sure why I'm still getting duplicates.

```
 SELECT 
      AssetScores.Department, AssetScores.Evaluator, (Avg(AssetScores.[Final 
      Score]/100)) AS [Average Score], Count(AssetScores.[Final Score]) AS 
      Completed
 FROM 
      AssetScores
 WHERE 
     (((Month([Date of Review]))=Month(Now())) AND ((Year([Date of 
        Review]))=Year(Now())))
 GROUP BY 
     AssetScores.Department, AssetScores.Evaluator, AssetScores.[date of 
     review];
```

Expected Results:

```
Department    Evaluator   Average Score     Completed
Collections   Melissa Martinez  1           1
Collections   Qiana Bridges         1           3
Collections   Robert Sutowski   1           1
Profit & Loss     Wanda Tavitas         1           2
Recovery      Pete Rodriguez    1           2
Servicing     Crystal Zamarripa     1          11
Servicing     Richard Paez          1          11
Speciality        Patrick Ryan          0.95            8
Vendor Relations  Monica Garza          0.92           10
```

Current Results

```
Department    Evaluator   Average Score     Completed
Collections   Melissa Martinez  1           1
Collections   Qiana Bridges         1           3
Collections   Robert Sutowski   1           1
Profit & Loss     Wanda Tavitas         1           1
Profit & Loss     Wanda Tavitas         1           1
Recovery      Pete Rodriguez    1           2
Servicing     Crystal Zamarripa     1          11
Servicing     Richard Paez          1          11
Speciality        Patrick Ryan          0.95            8
Vendor Relations  Monica Garza          0.95           10
Vendor Relations  Monica Garza          0.90            9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query currently has 3 non-aggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
 GROUP BY 
    AssetScores.Department, 
    AssetScores.Evaluator, 
    AssetScores.[date of review]
```

However from your expected output it seems like you don't need the date of review. I would suggest to change the `GROUP BY` clause to :

```
 GROUP BY 
    AssetScores.Department, 
    AssetScores.Evaluator
```

Comment: I was just typing this out.  I would be interested to see AssetScores.[date of review] included in the columns.

Comment: @AlecThomas : oh ok, then you should just add this field to your SELECT clause. But please keep in mind that this might generate an output with the same evaluator on multiple records (only with different dates of review)...

Comment: @AlexThomas : also if you consider that my answer properly responded to your question, please consider accepting it so the community can benefit from it... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same columns in your SELECT list as in the GROUP BY (except the aggregate functions of course) so remove the last column from the GROUP BY